# ASP.NET MVC3 Client-Side Validation with alert

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

is there a way out of the box to display the client side validation message through an alert instead of span?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the jQuery validator, so you should be able to do the usual:

```
if (jQuery.validator) {
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this works on the client side, but if I add an error to the ModelState on the server side it doesn't work. I guess there is no MVC3 OOB...

Comment: You'd need to (1) write CSS rules which hide the `div` returned by the server-side validations and (2) show it in an `alert` on `$.ready()`. That said, pages which show a browser-modal dialog on load are kind of obnoxious on a multi-tabbed browser.

Comment: This is an ASP.NET MVC project with multiple views for certain device types. This specific view is for the iPhone/iPod using the iWebKit. We're not worried about the alert being annoying.