# Difference between 'Html.Validate' and 'Html.ValidateFor'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Why do we use `.Validate` and `.Validatefor` in validation?

I am using that, but I am not getting any error message in the UI.

#### Code

```
<div>
    @{Html.BeginForm();}
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { id = "txtLastName" })
    @{Html.Validate("LastName");}
    @{Html.ValidateFor(x=>x.LastName);}
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
    @{Html.EndForm();}
</div>
```

Comment: @PKKG See my new post

Answer (score 13):

This behavior is intentional. Both these helpers just register corresponding parameters for client-side validation, without actually showing any message should the validation fail. However this message can still be displayed in a `ValidationSummary`.

If you want to show the message specific to the field/parameter, you should use `ValidationMessage` or `ValidationMessageFor` instead:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("LastName")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.LastName)
```

Comment: I tried without using Validate and Validate For , The error message in property is displayed in ValidationSummary. My Question is like in which situation we use validate and validatefor

Comment: @user2688364, you should use them when you want to trigger client validation for the field, but do not want to show any validation message.

Comment: Please share some idea about how to use alert for displaying the error message on client side

Comment: @user2688364, here is [one way to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069739/asp-net-mvc3-client-side-validation-with-alert)

Answer (score 3):

If there are situations where you don't actually want a validation message to visually appear for each field (i.e. by using Html.ValidationMessage), but would rather allow a summary to be the sole source of validation error messages (i.e. by using Html.ValidationSummary), you still need some way to "trigger" the validation to occur for the specific fields you want it to. This can be achieved by using the Html.Validate/Html.ValidateFor<> methods within your view. Those helpers won't render anything, but will simply register the specified field for client-side validation.

See this post for answer [How does validation in ASP.NET MVC 2 actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581344/how-does-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-2-actually-work/1583887#1583887)